# Access current page name from __layout.svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a bunch of routes in a directory, with a common `__layout.svelte` file, let's say a following structure:

```
- src
  - routes
    - common
      - __layout.svelte
      - page_a.svelte
      - page_b.svelte
```

I'd like to know in `__layout.svelte` the name of the page I'm currently in. E.g. when I'm on `/common/page_a` I want `__layout` to display `page_a`. This would be easy if I'd have dynamic routing and a file `[name].svelte`, then I could access `name` value by `page.params.name`, but since these are static I don't know how to access it reliably in another way than parsing the URL.

Comment: There's unfortunately no built-in way to do it other than via `page.url` and `page.routeId`.

Comment: I use {#each} loop like this: <a {href} class:active={$page.url.pathname === href}>{title}</a>

Answer (score 15):

SvelteKit provides a store named `page`, you can import it as

```
import {page} from '$app/stores'
```

Since it's a store you can access the value like this `$page.url.pathname` and it will be reactive, if you only want the last part of the url you can use some *string methods* to extract it for this specific one.

Something like this would work

```
$page.url.pathname.substr($page.url.pathname.lastIndexOf('/'))
```

Comment: `substr` is deprecated, use `slice`